# Can I apply survival analysis to predict if a user will revisit the website?

Tags: predictive-modeling, churn, aggregation, survival-analysis

I have one business problem in hand which is to predict if a user will revisit the website or not within 6 months. I need to majorly understand what are the factors which make the user return and also need to give business recommendations on what can be done to make a new user return to the website.
My initial idea was to do logistic regression. Lately, I read about survival analysis. I want to know if I can use survival analysis for this problem.
Also, my dataset has 20k users; each user having multiple transactions; the target variable was not given
I aggregated the dataset to one record per user and did some feature engineering to come up with a target variable.
If I want to use survival analysis in this problem, shall I consider only the last transaction of each user or shall I use the aggregated dataset?

Comment: I'm not expert in survival analysis but I thought it was useful only for studying a population over time, so if I'm right that doesn't seem a good fit for predicting whether a particular user will revisit. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use survival analysis (which can be more flexible and insightful), I'd recommend [this package](https://lifetimes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [this great tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-customer-lifetime-value-with-buy-til-you-die-probabilistic-models-in-python-f5cac78758d9). Speaking shortly, as a result, you'll get "probability of being alive" for each customer.

If you want to use logistic regression I think it's trickier. Why I think so - Like any other churn problem, it's hard to define it properly. The definition depends on your task and where the model outcome will be used. Let's say churn is a particular amount of inactivity, e.g. 30 days. You can do an initial analysis of how to find this number. Just pick a particular date (you can do it multiple times) and check % of people who made next transaction. Important thing is - your time period from both sides should be same for all users:

- if it's a new users he's not able to be inactive for a long period, right?
- if it's a last date in the dataset (e.g. yesterday) - not all users are not able to perform transaction within 1 day. And you'll get high churn rates. So be attentive to dates.

So you need to understand from your data - which inactivity is "normal" for the average user and define it as N. After that you can label users binary like "if inactivity > N then "churned (1)" else "not churned (0)"". And you can use this label with any classification model.